# Render action on all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What a correct way to render action (i.e. 'news') for all pages? I want something like this:

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
 <div class="side">
  <%= render :template => 'news/index' %> 
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <%= yield %>
 </div>
...
</html>
```

and news_controller.rb

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @news_previews = News.news_for_quick_preview
    render :layout => false 
  end
end
```

But now it's not working. @news_previews => nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `before_filter :load_news` in application controller

```
before_filter :load_news 
def load_news
  @news_previews = News.news_for_quick_preview
end
```